# What could cause "can't link with a main executable" on a shared library?

Tags: c++, macos, linker

I get a "can't link with a main executable" when trying to link a precompiled library to a main file when compiling.

```
hostname:folder user$ g++ -o add testadd.cc -ladd -lmultiply -L.
ld: in ./libmultiply.dylib, can't link with a main executable
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
hostname:folder user$
```

both libs (add and multiply) where compiled before, and are present in the same directory.

Can anyone give me a hint what can cause this error?

Thanx

PS: OSX 10.6.4 with g++-4.2.1

Comment: Please show us how you build the libraries - both compile and link commands.

Comment: Do you have defined a main() function inside one of your libraries?

Answer (score 1):

FYI:

When using the compiler-switch -dynamiclib and you get the above mentioned error,
try compiling with -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup instead.

For me that worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like somebody has had a similar problem: [ld can't link with a main executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179804/ld-cant-link-with-a-main-executable)

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around a bit, and apparently I fixed it...

Before I compiled the shared lib with

```
g++ -o libmultiply.dylib libmultiply.cc -dynamiclib
```

and received the mentioned Error. Now I recompiled the lib again, with

```
g++ -o libmultiply.dylib libmultiply.cc -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup
```

and it seems to work now. (At least the compiling and linking.) 
But I still need to check, whether the lib actually does what it is suposed to. ;)

Up until now I dunno why the linking now does not report the error, but maybe someone else can shed some light into that with these infos. =)

just my 2 ct.